# Question on the Rising Sun Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a problem from Tao's blog.

Let ${f: {\bf R} \rightarrow {\bf R}}$ be an absolutely integrable function, and let ${f^*: {\bf R} \rightarrow {\bf R}}$ be the one-sided signed Hardy-Littlewood maximal function

$\displaystyle f^*(x) := \sup_{h>0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{[x,x+h]} f(t)\ dt$.

Show that $\forall \lambda > 0$,

$\displaystyle \lambda m( \{ f^*(x) > \lambda \} ) = \int_{x: f^*(x) > \lambda} f(x)\ dx$.

The hint suggest that we first try the case when ${f}$ has compact support, in which case one can apply the rising sun lemma to a sufficiently large interval containing the support of ${f}$. In applying the rising sun lemma to the function  ${F: [a,b] \rightarrow {\bf R}}$ defined by $\displaystyle F(x) := \int_{[a,x]} f(t)\ dt - (x-a) \lambda$, I was trying to show that $a_n = a$ and $F(b_n) > F(a_n) = F(a)$ will lead to a contradiction when $\lambda > 0$, but was stuck. Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: Though your question is self-contained, please give the URL of this question in order people can access at once to the **context** of the original question.

Comment: See Exercise 31 https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/245a-notes-5-differentiation-theorems/#hlmax

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it called the Rising Sun Inequality?

Comment: @Mike https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rising_sun_lemma